# displaying still images in drawables on text input on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, image, text

I'm a newbie here, sorry for the dumb question. I am trying to display an image in drawables that is equal value with the text inputted in edittext.

For example I input "A" and a certain image will appear in the next activity after I click done.

My personal idea is that, this will be done in imageview, but how about if I enter "ABC" and 3 images equal to the inputted text will appear simultaneously.

I think array will be use in this problem but I have no idea how to start.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iamgeActivity);
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //my problem starts here
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right..you can do it like in first activity, on clicking `done` button take the name of image from editText to next activity through bundle.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(currentactivity.this, nextactivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imagename",youreditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In next activity take this image name from bundle and use following code to set image in your imageview dynamically:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageid);
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. we managed to display just one image every one character, my problem now is that how to display consecutive images.. 

EX. from A-Z, every letter has its equal image, then i typed "ABC", it will display 3 images equal to A, B, C.

i think i will use array but i dont where to start. i hope i can get more help from you thanks! :)